# android room databaseview can't select from table

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, androidx, android-jetpack

I created a DatabaseView, to join two tables. When I am doing my query, I am not being able to select from the database view table. But it can be a return type.
It's giving me cannot resolve symbol EmployeeWithRole.
I'm using roomVersion = '2.1.0-alpha04

My entities:

```
@Entity(tableName = "EmployeeRole")
   data class EmployeeRole(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Id,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "role")
    val role: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "parentRole")
    val parentRole: Id?)


@Entity(tableName = "Employee",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = EmployeeRole::class,
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                parentColumns = ["id"],
                childColumns = ["currentRoleId"]
        )])
 data class Employee(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Id,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "firstName")
    val firstName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lastName")
    val lastName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "currentRoleId")
    var currentRoleId: Id,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pictureUrl")
    var pictureUrl: String)
```

My Dao:

```
@Dao
Interface EmployeeWithRoleDao {
  @Query(" SELECT * FROM EmployeeWithRole ")
   fun getAllEmployees(): List<EmployeeWithRole>
}
```

My database view:

```
import androidx.room.DatabaseView
import androidx.room.Embedded

@DatabaseView("""
SELECT Employee.*, $employeeRoleParams FROM Employee
  INNER JOIN EmployeeRole ON Employee.currentRoleId = EmployeeRole.id
""")

 data class EmployeeWithRole(
    @Embedded
    val employee: Employee,
    @Embedded(prefix = employeeRoleP)
    val employeeRole: EmployeeRole
)

private const val employeeRoleP = "EmployeeRole"
private const val employeeRoleParams = """
$employeeRoleP.id as ${employeeRoleP}_id,
$employeeRoleP.role as ${employeeRoleP}_role,
$employeeRoleP.parentRole as ${employeeRoleP}_parentRole
"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import androidx.room.DatabaseView
import androidx.room.Embedded

 @DatabaseView(baseQuery)
 data class EmployeeWithRole(
    @Embedded
    val employee: Employee,
    @Embedded(prefix = employeeRoleP + "_")
    val employeeRole: EmployeeRole)

 const val employeeRoleP = "EmployeeRole"
 private const val employeeRoleParams = """
        $employeeRoleP.id as ${employeeRoleP}_id,
        $employeeRoleP.role as ${employeeRoleP}_role,
        $employeeRoleP.parentRole as ${employeeRoleP}_parentRole
    """

 const val baseQuery = """
        SELECT Employee.*, $employeeRoleParams FROM Employee
        INNER JOIN EmployeeRole ON Employee.currentRoleId = EmployeeRole.id
    """
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to naming issue, You have named your table in Entity as `EmployeeRole` where as in you Dao you are accessing it using `EmployeeWithRole`. You need to keep both the names same.

Comment: DatabaseView should behave like a normal POJO. So my naming is correct. I am following the same approach from this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sU-ot_Oz3AE&t=209s , watch from  7:17

Comment: check and verify from this codelabs https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#4

Comment: Check this link to know more about what I am trying to do : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/creating-views#kotlin

Comment: error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [id,role] in EmployeeWithRole even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [id,firstName,lastName,currentRoleId,pictureUrl,localUpdatedDate,localInsertedDate,EmployeeRole_id,EmployeeRole_role,EmployeeRole_parentRole]
    public abstract java.util.List<EmployeeWithRole> getAllEmployees();

Answer (score 0):

try annotate the EmployeeWithRole with @Entity("EmployeeWithRole")